# WPF/XAML - Animate Expander Content

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, expander

I am trying to add an expander animation using xaml (similar to the one used by windows 10) where on click it slides new information out from under the expander bar (scrolls from **bottom to top**). An example of what I am trying to achieve can be found in Windows 10 by going to Control Panel, Power Options, and clicking the expander beside "Show additional plans".

I have got the animation to kind of work, but if I set the window property SizeToContent="Height" (which I ultimately want to use so that the window size automatically adjusts to fit its contents) the expanded information scrolls from **top to bottom** instead! If I manually adjust the window height using the handle bar (even just by just 1 pixel) and then click the expander again, then the animation works the way I want it to (**bottom to top**) but then the expanded information scrolls past the top of the window >_<.

Any ideas?

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="480"
        SizeToContent="Height">

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

        <!-- --><TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0" Height="21">TITLE</TextBlock>

        <!-- First Panel -->
        <StackPanel>

            <!-- First Panel Style -->
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibility" />
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="StackPanelMain">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Expanded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.25" To="160" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Collapsed">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 5 0 0" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="360" />
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            <!-- First Panel Code -->
            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource StackPanelMain}" Height="21">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0">First Panel</TextBlock>
                    <Separator Margin="5 0 5 0" Opacity="0.5" Width="360"/>
                    <Expander x:Name="FirstPanelExpander" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=FirstPanelExpander, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}">
                    <TextBox />
                    <TextBox />
                    <TextBox />
                    <TextBox />
                    <TextBox />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Next Panel -->
        <StackPanel Height="21">

            <!-- Next Panel Code -->
            <TextBlock Margin="5 0 0 0">Next Panel</TextBlock>

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to hide your `Textboxes`. When your objects are inside the `Expander` they will already be hidden if the `expander` is closed. Below is an example of a design that is close to what you want.

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Expander" x:Key="ExpanderMain">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Expanded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="30" To="160" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Expander.Collapsed">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="160" To="30" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 5 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="360" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Name="AnimatedExpander" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderMain}">
            <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Panel - 1" />
                    <Separator Width="300" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>

        <Expander Name="AnimatedExpander2" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderMain}">
            <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Panel - 2" />
                    <Separator Width="300" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>

        <Expander Name="AnimatedExpander3" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderMain}">
            <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Panel - 3" />
                    <Separator Width="300" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>

        <Expander Name="AnimatedExpander4" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderMain}">
            <Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Panel - 4" />
                    <Separator Width="300" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: thanks for the tips, but functionally your code does the same thing mine does. the box still loads from top to bottom when the expander is clicked, and if the window is manually resized it has the exact same problem as mine (where the fields load from bottom to top, but load outside of the window and make the expander and the first few top fields unclickable) :o

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I fixed it above for you. When it encloses its expanders in the scrollViewer, the scrollViewer area will open and close according to the page content.

Comment: What is the same thing he does? Did you literally copy all the code?

Comment: I'm guessing you're taking one of the Expanders and setting it to `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"`. In this case, an upward opening is made.
I don't think you have `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` set in the design example on the page you're talking about. There are Expanders lined up one after the other.

Comment: Pulling the scrollViewer down when the expanders are opened will give the same design example. That's what it looks like in the view, as the ScrollViewer goes down after the expander is opened.

Comment: yea, i copied all your code. it's animating the expander content from **top to bottom.** 
If you take my original code, click [start] in visual studio, manually drag out the window to make it taller, and then click the expander, this will show you how I want the textboxes to animate - from **bottom to top**. It might be easier to see how it is animating if you change the duration time from 0:0:0.25 to 0:0:1. Bottom to top is how windows 10 animates expander content, and I want the wpf expander to animate the same way.

Comment: the problem is that to achieve this animation, I either need a whole bunch of blank space above the expander, or the expanded content goes past the top of the window. To fix this, I think what i need to do is somehow set the vertical alignment of the panels to "top" while setting the verticalalignment of expander content to "bottom" if that makes sense. but the only way I have found to set the vertical alignment of the expander content to bottom, is by setting the outer most panel to bottom which bottom aligns everything :o.

Comment: In the area you mentioned, the expandar opens from top to bottom. That's why I think it's the same as a design example. Maybe the `ExpandDirection` feature can be tried to open in the opposite direction.